# Git history rewrite messed up branch

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

One time, I accidentally pushed a commit to the remote repository with the wrong author email. I used

```
git filter-branch -f --env-filter "GIT_AUTHOR_NAME='Niklas Rosenstein'; GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL='<<email>>'; GIT_COMMITTER_NAME='Niklas Rosenstein'; GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL='<<email>>';" HEAD
```

to rewrite the history. Then I used

```
$ git push origin development
    Enter passphrase for key '----':
    To git@gitlab_cip:rosenstein/beak.git
     ! [rejected]        development -> development (non-fast-forward)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'git@gitlab_cip:rosenstein/beak.git'
    hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
    hint: its remote counterpart. Merge the remote changes (e.g. 'git pull')
    hint: before pushing again.
    hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

$ git pull origin development
    Enter passphrase for key '----':
    From gitlab_cip:rosenstein/beak
     * branch            development -> FETCH_HEAD
    Merge made by the 'recursive' strategy.

$ git push origin development
    Enter passphrase for key '----':
    Counting objects: 430, done.
    Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
    Compressing objects: 100% (336/336), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (402/402), 43.93 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
    Total 402 (delta 262), reused 85 (delta 65)
    To git@gitlab_cip:rosenstein/beak.git
       dd06969..2b2ddb4  development -> development
```

Which probably was a huge mistake.

[image: graph]

I got all commits doubled! The wrong commit's author was fixed (well duplicated, then changed), but the original commit exists, too!

I later read that I (probably) should have used

```
git push origin --force development fix
```

Can I fix this somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If nobody has recently pulled from your remote repo, you can:

```
git checkout development

# Make sure you don't have any work in progress
# That will cancel the merge (assuming you didn't make any new commits on it)
git reset --hard HEAD^1

# replace the development branch by your new history
git push origin --force development
```

(From the [SPECIFYING REVISIONS](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_revisions) section of the [`git rev-parse` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse))

I used `^1` instead of `~1` in order to select the first parent (which is in your development branch), instead of the second parent (which is the one from origin/development, merged into your branch).
That being said, `~1` (first ancestor) would probably work too.

Comment: @NiklasR Ok, I just explained a bit why I went at first with `^1`.

Comment: I received *$ git reset --hard HEAD^1
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD1': unknown revision or path not in the w
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'* when using `HEAD^1`. Edit: Oh wait if I remember right, ^ is special character in the Windows console..

Comment: @NiklasR yes, in a windows console, I have trouble too using `^`. Maybe `^^1` (escaping the escape `^` sign)